# How can I reset my Product Name to default in info.plist in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, info.plist

I was working on a WatchKit companion app, and I changed the name of the app in iTunes Connect, so I wanted to correspondingly change the name of the WatchKit companion app (I assumed Product Name in info.plist was the place to change it). Now I can't get it back to the default $ value and clear this error: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset any of the build settings to default:

1. Select the row you'd like to reset.
2. Press delete.

EDIT: This will reset the row to it's default value (if there is one), but won't necessarily set it back to the default project template. You'll notice that even when a new project is created, the Product Name row is bolded, which means it has been overridden.

Product Name doesn't have a default value, but many rows in Build Settings do, such as Base SDK or Code Signing Identity, so when you delete those rows, they will be restored as described.

Comment: doesn't seem to do anything?  (tried delete and fn + delete)

Comment: When you create a new project, it will set Product Name to $(TARGET_NAME). Delete sets the row to it's default value (if there is one), which there isn't for Product Name. I'll update the answer.